# How can I use Azure Active Directory Users as virtual machine users?

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-virtual-machine, azure-active-directory

Is there a way, to use Users in an Azure Active Directory as Users for an Azure Virtual Machine? Respectively, is there in general a way to create multiple user accounts for an Azure Virtual Machine?

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Azure AD users to login to a VM. Azure AD is NOT a domain controller.

The general way to create multiple user accounts in Azure VM is by remote desktopping into it and create user accounts from user accounts section in control panel / computer management.